Can not disable auto-correct in Gmail chat
A few weeks ago Gmail started to auto-correct the text I type into its Chat window. This is a major problem for me, because I use Gmail in English but type in Hungarian as well, which then gets auto-corrected to similar English words. For example, if I type "gondoltam", it gets auto-corrected to "gondola" (which is an unrelated word).
The first time I noticed this, I opened Gmail's Settings and found a section for Autocorrect, which I subsequently set to "Autocorrect off". However, the text I type in Chat still gets auto-corrected. I also considered that it may be Firefox that does this, but I found no such feature or setting in Firefox. It also only happens in Gmail and not on other sites.
How can I disable this annoying behavior?
Not a duplicate
This is not a duplicate of How to disable permanently Gmail spell checker. That question is about spell checker settings for emails and this one is about autocorrect in Chat.

@zoltan I'm reviewing closed questions. You mentioned "chat window". Is this issue in a Chat window or an email window?

@Blindspots this issue was about chat windows and I could not control this behavior with any of the settings. However, when I checked back a few weeks later, I found a new setting that I could use to turn this off under "Chat & Meet" → "Manage Chat Settings". Either it was added later or I missed it the first time.

@Zoltan thanks for responding I was reviewing closed questions and that differentiates it from the other question. I think you are right about the solution. It is a bit ambiguous and tucked away.  I was also going to suggest that if it was reopened.  You should self-answer to help the next person

When I checked back a few weeks later, I found a new setting that I could use to turn Chat auto-correct off under "Chat & Meet" → "Manage Chat Settings". (This setting was either added later or I missed it the first time.)
